# Prevent users accessing certain apex applications

Tags: oracle-apex

We have 50 apex applications which currently any user can access any of the 50 applications by using the website links on our intranet page.

How can you determine which users can access certain apex forms - I'm assuming lots of different apex groups will need to be made and people will need assigned to each group?

This is ok but i can see it getting out of hand trying to manage all the groups. I thought there must be a better way though of preventing users from accessing applications?

Any ideas on how to prevent users credentials working on some applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use authorization schemes, which can be applied at any level (e.g. the whole application, individual pages, regions, items, etc.).

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23903_01/doc/doc.41/e21674/sec_authorization.htm